# partial derivative of an integral - specific examples

Tags: partial-differential-equations, partial-derivative

My problem are the partial derivatives of an integral. I've read about the Leibniz rule but I'm not sure how it can be applied in the cases below (if at all).

Let $f \in C^1(\mathbb{R}^2)$ and $a,t,x,s \in \mathbb{R}$. I'm working on the following integrals:

$$\partial_t    \big{(} \int\limits_{0}^t  f(x-a(t-s),s) ds\big{)}  $$
respectively

$$ \partial_x    \big{(} \int\limits_{0}^t  f(x-a(t-s),s) ds\big{)} $$

whereas $x$ and $t$ are the variables of the equations where these integrals are part of.

I assume that in the second case, I can simply put $\partial_x$ into the integral.

I would be very grateful for any ideas or suggestions. Thank you!

Comment: You can definitely just apply the Leibniz rule directly, in the second case the bounds on the integral do not depend on x so you are justified in your assumption

Comment: You are right about the second one (although differentiation under the integral sign needs justification). For the first one, just apply [Leibniz' rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_integral_rule) and the chain rule.